# OpenglSE For Xbox One

Tags: uwp, angle, xbox

I'm creating an app that uses OpenglSE + swapchainpanel it's working perfectly on the computer, but on xbox one the screen is black, if I click the home button I see the image in the background when minimizing the app, if I define how WARP works normally, has anyone gone through this know how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I'm creating this way

```
   static const EGLint backendD3D11[] =
{
    // These are the default display attributes, used to request ANGLE's D3D11
     // renderer.
     // eglInitialize will only succeed with these attributes if the hardware
     // supports D3D11 Feature Level 10_0+.
     EGL_PLATFORM_ANGLE_TYPE_ANGLE,
     EGL_PLATFORM_ANGLE_TYPE_D3D11_ANGLE,

     EGL_PLATFORM_ANGLE_D3D11ON12_ANGLE,
     EGL_TRUE,

     //EGL_PLATFORM_ANGLE_DEVICE_TYPE_ANGLE, EGL_PLATFORM_ANGLE_DEVICE_TYPE_D3D_WARP_ANGLE,

     // EGL_EXPERIMENTAL_PRESENT_PATH_ANGLE is an optimization that
     // can have large performance benefits on mobile devices.
     EGL_EXPERIMENTAL_PRESENT_PATH_ANGLE,
     EGL_EXPERIMENTAL_PRESENT_PATH_FAST_ANGLE,

     // EGL_PLATFORM_ANGLE_ENABLE_AUTOMATIC_TRIM_ANGLE is an option that
     // enables ANGLE to automatically call
     // the IDXGIDevice3::Trim method on behalf of the application when it gets
     // suspended.
     // Calling IDXGIDevice3::Trim when an application is suspended is a
     // Windows Store application certification
     // requirement.
     EGL_PLATFORM_ANGLE_ENABLE_AUTOMATIC_TRIM_ANGLE,
     EGL_TRUE,
     EGL_NONE,
};
```